# LeetCode Dynamic Programming Robber Question Mistake

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I am currently doing [LeetCode's Robber Question](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/). I passed 68/69 test cases, and the only one I failed is the following: an array full or zeros like this [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.....]. Can you please explain to me how to fix my code to fix this error? Also, if you have any suggestions about optimization, please let me know! My code:

```
class Solution {
public int rob(int[] nums) {

    if (nums.length == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (nums.length == 1) {
        return nums[0];
    }

    int[] memo = new int[nums.length];

    return Math.max(dp(0, nums, memo), dp(1, nums, memo));


}


public int dp(int index, int[] nums, int[] memo)  {

    int max;

    if (memo[index] != 0) {
        return memo[index];
    }


    if (index == nums.length - 1 || index == nums.length - 2) {
        max = nums[index];
    } else if (index == nums.length - 3) {
        max = nums[index] + nums[nums.length - 1];
    }
        else {
        max = Math.max(nums[index] + dp(index + 2, nums, memo), nums[index] + dp(index + 3, nums, memo));
    }

    memo[index] = max;
    return max;









}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have solved the same problem using bottom up DP which handles every test cases.

```
class Solution {
    public int rob(int[] nums) {
     int n=nums.length;
     if(n==0)
         return 0;
     if(n==1)
          return nums[0];

     int[] dp= new int[n];
     dp[0]=nums[0];
     dp[1]=Math.max(nums[0],nums[1]);
     for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
      dp[i]=Math.max(dp[i-1],dp[i-2]+nums[i]);
      return dp[n-1];   
    }
```

The reason your code is failing for [0,0,0,0....] is because the answer is zero and your recursion base case `if(memo[index] != 0)` is never getting satisfied and resulting in StackOverflow . Below is the correct version of your code

```
 class Solution {
    public int rob(int[] nums) {

        if (nums.length == 0 ) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (nums.length == 1) {
            return nums[0];
        }

        int[] memo = new int[nums.length];
        Arrays.fill(memo,Integer.MAX_VALUE); // add this to check if memo is not updated
        return Math.max(dp(0, nums, memo), dp(1, nums, memo));


    }


    public int dp(int index, int[] nums, int[] memo)  {

        int max;

        if (memo[index] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) { // check for this condition 
            return memo[index];
        }


        if (index == nums.length - 1 || index == nums.length - 2) {
            max = nums[index];
        } else if (index == nums.length - 3) {
            max = nums[index] + nums[nums.length - 1];
        }
            else {
            max = Math.max(nums[index] + dp(index + 2, nums, memo), nums[index] + dp(index + 3, nums, memo));
        }

        memo[index] = max;
        return max;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about the bottom-up approach for a while, but could not come up with this. Still not sure why my code is not working for that last case tho... (I do get 100 percent accuracy without that)

Comment: for the 69 test case the answer is [0] but your recursion base case is never getting satifisfied resulting in 'Time Limit' Exceeded in LeetCode. and StackOverflow in my local system .  Marke Arrays.fill(memo,Integer.MAX_VALUE) and check for that in your base case